# call a face detection listener inside a thread in android

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, video-capture, face-detection

I'm trying to detect faces inside a thread. outside of that thread it works pretty well , so I don't understand why the listener is never called.another important thing-it's implemented inside a GLSurfaceView class.
the relevant code inside that thread (the thread constructor and then the thread function startPreview that should make the detection):

```
public CameraThread(final CameraGLView parent) {
        super("Camera thread");
        this.myFaceDetector = new Camera.FaceDetectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
                Log.v("face detect", "face");
            }//myFaceDetector;
        };
    }
private final void startPreview(final int width, final int height) {    
    try {
                CAMERA_ID = findFrontFacingCamera();//front camera id
                mCamera = Camera.open(CAMERA_ID);
                mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(myFaceDetector);
        }
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

        if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0) {
            mCamera.startFaceDetection();
        }
 }
```

Comment: If your method call an openGLDraw Context you need to invoke from the mainthread or synchronize because of opengl buffers.

Comment: can I implement such thing from inside the thread ?

Comment: You can capture the camera stream from another thread and then make opengl operation on the main thread.

Comment: what do you mean in opengl (most of the code here is not mine), and how can I use the Camera instance twice at the same time ?